# mobiscroll for jquery: how to use language module

Tags: mobiscroll

How do I use the language module for mobiscroll? I am missing some "link" between the initialization and the extended language function.

```
 (function ($) {
    $.mobiscroll.i18n.de = $.extend($.mobiscroll.i18n.de, {
        setText: 'OK',
        cancelText: 'Abbrechen'
    });
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $.mobiscroll.i18n.de = $.extend($.mobiscroll.i18n.de, {
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        ...
        yearText: 'Jahr'
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $("#scroller").mobiscroll().date();
});
```

(And, I'm open to suggestions for other good pop-up calendars for mobile devices. jquery datepicker was too slow and the plain calendar for mobiscroll costs money)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like so:

```
mob_dict = {dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', ...}


$(function(){
    $("#scroller").mobiscroll().date(mobi_dict);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a German Language pack, it can be selected from the download package builder. No need for a custom one.